# Couchbase subdoc updates in NodeJs SDK

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I want to add Phone number objects to my Person Document which will hold them in an Array. So far so good i have no problem adding new phone Docs to the array. Here is where it gets a bit tricky if i want to update a doc in the array via subdoc i need to know the index in array and here comes my concern. Couchbase lets user append, prep-end into an array. So even so i can get the array indexes when i original retrieve the array there is a slight chance someone might have pushed new element into array which could have changed the index. So that would require to use CAS before i update or delete any array objects.
So is there a way to overcome all of these limitations and still avoid multiple round trips.

Here is what my doc looks like

```
{
  "type": "Lead",
  "person": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Tom",
      "middle_name": "M",
      "last_name": "Miller",
      "title": "Dr.",
      "suffix": "II",
      "gender": "m",
      "dob": "07/12/1978",
      "email": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "email_address": "tom@email.com",
          "default": "yes"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "email_address": "tom@email.com"
        }
      ],
      "phone": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "country": "+1",
          "phone_number": 2135551212,
          "ext": "",
          "type": "mobile",
          "sms": "yes",
          "default": "yes"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "country": "+1",
          "phone_number": 2135554444,
          "ext": 455,
          "type": "office",
          "sms": "no"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "home_address": {
    "street_address": "28812 Miller Ave",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "CA",
    "zip": 90017,
    "country": "US"
  },
  "search_info": {
    "min_beds": 3,
    "min_bath": 2.5,
    "min_garage": 2,
    "garage_type": "any",
    "pool": "yes",
    "min_sqft": 2500,
    "max_sqft": 3500,
    "min_lot_size": 10000,
    "max_lot_size": 15000,
    "max_storey": 1,
    "notes": "Wants a fixer upper"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have a CAS value, you can specify it when building the Sub-Document request. If you want to add the phone number without reading the document first, N1QL is probably the way to go.